# buscar todos os registos dos ultimos 12 meses incluindo zero

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a minha tabela `bud_quotations` e quero ir buscar todos os registos que foram inseridos nos últimos 12 meses, incluindo os meses que não tenham qualquer registo.

Agora a contagem não está a funcionar, devolvendo sempre zero na contagem. E o que eu quero é um resultado semelhante a este:

```
+------+----+-----------------------------+
| y    | m  | Cbud_quotations.created_at) |
+------+----+-----------------------------+
| 2016 |  4 |                 5595        |
| 2016 |  5 |                 4431        |
| 2016 |  6 |                 3299        |
| 2016 |  7 |                  429        |
| 2016 |  8 |                    0        |
| 2016 |  9 |                 3698        |
| 2016 | 10 |                 6208        |
| 2016 | 11 |                 5142        |
| 2016 | 12 |                 1196        |
| 2017 |  1 |                   10        |
| 2017 |  2 |                    0        |
| 2017 |  3 |                    0        |
+------+----+-----------------------------+
```

O meu campo de criação, `created_at`, é do tipo `DATETIME`. A minha query é a seguinte:

```
 SELECT y, m, Count(bud_quotations.created_at)
 FROM (
  SELECT y, m
  FROM
     (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
     (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
       UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
       UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months) ym
   LEFT JOIN bud_quotations
   ON ym.y = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(bud_quotations.created_at))
      AND ym.m = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(bud_quotations.created_at))
 WHERE
   (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
   OR
   (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
 GROUP BY y, m;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimenta tirar o `FROM_UNIXTIME`:

```
SELECT y, m, Count(bud_quotations.created_at)
 FROM (
  SELECT y, m
  FROM
     (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
     (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
       UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
       UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months) ym
   LEFT JOIN bud_quotations
   ON ym.y = YEAR(bud_quotations.created_at)
      AND ym.m = MONTH(bud_quotations.created_at)
 WHERE
   (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
   OR
   (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
 GROUP BY y, m;
```